# "null upcall object" in SWIG-generated JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I have a C++ Publication/Subscription service that uses RTI's DDS middleware to exchange messages.  This works correctly.  I use SWIG to generate JNI so Java applications can use the Publication/Subscription service.  This also works correctly.  We recently upgraded from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.x (with accompanying new gcc, Java, and DDS versions).  In this new environment, a pure C++ Pub/Sub application still works correctly.  However, in the new environment, when calling the Pub/Sub service in Java (via SWIG/JNI), I get about 50-60 successful pub/subs on different topics, and then the subscriptions stop receiving data.  I don't believe any specific message is causing the error.  I looked in the SWIG-generated JNI and I observe the following:

```
void SwigDirector_SubscriptionIssueListener_I::onIssueReceived(infrastructureservices::common::Message_T const *issue, infrastructureservices::pubsub::Subscription_I &subscription) throw() {
  JNIEnvWrapper swigjnienv(this) ;
  JNIEnv * jenv = swigjnienv.getJNIEnv() ;
  jobject swigjobj = (jobject) NULL ;
  jlong jissue = 0 ;
  jlong jsubscription = 0 ;

  if (!swig_override[0]) {
    SWIG_JavaThrowException(JNIEnvWrapper(this).getJNIEnv(), SWIG_JavaDirectorPureVirtual, "Attempted to invoke pure virtual method infrastructureservices::pubsub::SubscriptionIssueListener_I::onIssueReceived.");
    return;
  }
  swigjobj = swig_get_self(jenv); // *** THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE ***
  if (swigjobj && jenv->IsSameObject(swigjobj, NULL) == JNI_FALSE) {
    *((infrastructureservices::common::Message_T **)&jissue) = (infrastructureservices::common::Message_T *) issue;
    *(infrastructureservices::pubsub::Subscription_I **)&jsubscription = (infrastructureservices::pubsub::Subscription_I *) &subscription;
    jenv->CallStaticVoidMethod(Swig::jclass_cfpubsubJNI, Swig::director_methids[7], swigjobj, jissue, jsubscription);
    if (jenv->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE) return ;
  } else {
    SWIG_JavaThrowException(jenv, SWIG_JavaNullPointerException, "null upcall object");
  }
  if (swigjobj) jenv->DeleteLocalRef(swigjobj);
}
```

Note the emphasized "swigjobj = swig_get_self(jenv);" line.  When the Java application is behaving well, this line is providing a good return value.  However, at some point mid-execution, this line starts returning NULL, and the subscriptions cease to be received.

To me this feels like some sort of resource is being exhausted.  I tried increasing -Xmx and -Xms to my Java application (which in previous circumstances fixed a similar symptom), but no luck there.  I used the SWIG ExceptionDescribe() method which outputs:

`Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: null upcall object`

which is basically just telling me what I already know.

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Comment: Doesn't RTI DDS generate Java code? Why convert to JNI?

Comment: While RTI DDS can generate Java code for the messages and topics, we have a more elaborate C++ pub/sub service built on top of RTI DDS that I need to use.  Hence the C++ and the JNI translation.

Comment: `JNIEnv * jenv = swigjnienv.getJNIEnv()` Does this always succeed? You don't seem to be checking the return value for `nullptr`. Maybe if you can check when `swig_get_self` returns `nullptr`.

Comment: JNIEnv * jenv = swigjnienv.getJNIEnv() appears to always succeed, even when swig_get_self starts returning nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I can confirm that adding:

`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

to the invocation of my Java application fixes this issue.